# How to make Swipe from every location of Screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, swipeview

i want to make a swipe function between layout , for flying out menu , like Facebook application , but every example and tutorial that i have seen it's all swipe from the leftest part of screen or rightest part of screen,but i want to swipe from every part of screen, like Viber, when you Swipe from middle of screen or anywhere it will swipe to left or right but i don't know how exactly it works,is there any example or tutorial to make a Swipe to right or left between layout from every where in screen , not just leftest or rightest part of screen,something like Viber app Swipe Gesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html

under the documentatin on how to implement Lateral Navigation, there even is a sample code for download :)

Comment: could you please help me more?because i don't know hot exactly call Swipe Action for sliding menu from everywhere in screen

Comment: try to take a look at the link i just gave you. There is a tutorial on how to create these swipe views using the ViewPager widget, available in the Support Library. Or the link that Francesco verheye gave you, thats an option as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial:

http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/working-with-gesture-api-in-android/

I used something like this before to capture a 'Z' gesture. You can create any gesture you want. It's easy to use.

My result:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3nGQ9djhqs&list=UUYTJ9XvTGqQVGevDMuNa6GA#t=281

(was my first app ever)

I'm not sure this will be the best solution for your needs but it will work.

Comment: i just want to Swipe between layout and when i swipe from every where in screen my menu comes out,but i dont know how implement function that call for swipe from everywhere in screen, please if you know get me some more help ;)